# Vue Deep Watcher doesnt trigger on data change

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, web

The countdown timer works well but the deep watcher doesnt work.
I made the deep watcher log the new value of seconds to console but it doesnt although the countdown timer keeps ticking.

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Countdown',
  data() {
    return {
      date_countdown: new Date('August 16, 2022').getTime(),
      date_current: {
        days: 0,
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: 0,
      },
      getDateDiff(date_countdown: number) {
        const date_current = new Date().getTime();
        const diff = date_countdown - date_current;
        const days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        const hours = Math.floor(
          (diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
        );
        const minutes = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        const seconds = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        return { days, hours, minutes, seconds };
      },
      timer() {
        return setInterval(() => {
          this.date_current = this.getDateDiff(this.date_countdown);
        }, 1000);
      },
    };
  },

  watch: {
    seconds: {
      deep: true,

      handler(newVal) {
        console.log(newVal); // to test the deep watcher; doesnt log tho
      },
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.timer();
  },

  beforeUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer());
  },
});
```

I'm not sure but maybe since the timer() function changes the value of `date_current` instead of changing `date_current.seconds` individually, the deep watcher is not triggered?

Answer (score 0):

That because you `watch` the `seconds` but seconds is not a direct property in the `data` or a computed property, If you want to watch the changes on `seconds` you need to apply `watch` event on `date_current` and inside the `watch` function get `date_current.seconds`.

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Countdown",
  data() {
    return {
      date_countdown: new Date("August 16, 2022").getTime(),
      date_current: {
        days: 0,
        hours: 0,
        minutes: 0,
        seconds: 0,
      },
      getDateDiff(date_countdown) {
        const date_current = new Date().getTime();
        const diff = date_countdown - date_current;
        const days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        const hours = Math.floor(
          (diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
        );
        const minutes = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        const seconds = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        return { days, hours, minutes, seconds };
      },
      timer() {
        return setInterval(() => {
          this.date_current = this.getDateDiff(this.date_countdown);
        }, 1000);
      },
    };
  },

  watch: {
    date_current: {
      deep: true,
      handler(newVal) {
        console.log(newVal.seconds); // to test the deep watcher; doesnt log tho
      },
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.timer();
  },

  beforeUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer());
  },
});
</script>
```

[This is a working code example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-browser-7bi2fe?file=/src/components/CountDown.vue:0-1328)

Comment: But what if I only want to check if `seconds` has changed instead of the whole object?

My code is pretty similar to this example: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/vue-deep-nesting/#implementing-deep-watching-in-nested-data-structures

and yet it wont work

Comment: I don't think the example he provided will work. you can only access to direct properties of `data` or `computed`, the benefit of `deep` is not access the nested properties directly, but if the nested properties change the watch on the parent object will trigger, that will not happen without the `deep` property.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken when you make this kind of equation;

```
this.date_current = this.getDateDiff(this.date_countdown);
```

watch just loses object reference since you set an entirely new object to it and vue uses proxies for reactive properties. So it loses its prior proxy and sets a new one but it doesn't trigger change. (maybe setting `immediate: true` helps but it's not well suited for this case.)

if you watch `date_current.seconds` then your watcher watches a primitive value and detects the change. (which is a better way to do it.)

Hope it helps.